# Python: how to make multiple selection in bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to choose a subsection from a selection.

I have a dataframe like the following.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['People'] = ['Eva', 'John', 'Paul','Mr a', 'Miss b', 'Mrs c' ]
df['Type']   = ['Students', 'Students', 'Students', 'Teachers', 'Teachers', 'Teachers']
```

Let say we have `Student` and `Teachers`.

```
select  =  Select(title="People",  options=['Student', 'Teachers' ])
```

Then we have three students: `Eva`, `John`, `Paul` and three teachers `Mr a`, `Miss b` and `Mrs c`

How can we create a second selection `select2` that choose `Eva`, `John`, `Paul` if we select teachers and `Mr a`, `Miss b` and `Mrs c` if we select `Teachers`.

```
select2  =  Select(title="Selected",  options=[ (`Eva`, `John`, `Paul`), (Mr a`, `Miss b`, `Mrs c`)] ])
```

This what I have in mind

```
select_data = Select(title="Type",  options=['None', 'Students', 'Teachers' ], value = '')
dynamic_select = Select(title = 'People', value = ''  , 
                        options = ['None','Eva', 'John', 'Paul','Mr a', 'Miss b', 'Mrs c' ] )
controls = widgetbox(select_data, dynamic_select)
layout = column(row(controls))

def update_layout(attr, old, new):
        if select_data.value == 'Students':
            dynamic_select = Select(title = 'People', value = '', options = ['Eva', 'John', 'Paul'])
        if select_data.value == 'Teachers':
            dynamic_select = Select(title = 'People', value = '', options = ['Mr a', 'Miss b', 'Mrs c'])
        if select_data.value == 'None':
            dynamic_select = Select(title = 'People', value = '', options = ['None'])     


select_data.on_change('value', update_layout)
dynamic_select.on_change('value', update_layout)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this code you can dynamically add / remove a second `Select` widget. Is this what you wanted?

```
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, show
from bokeh.models import Select, Column, Div
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np

students = ['Eva', 'John', 'Paul']
teachers = ['Mr a', 'Miss b', 'Mrs c']
select_data = Select(title="People",  options=['', 'Students', 'Teachers' ], value = '')
layout = Column(select_data)

def update_layout(attr, old, new):
    if new:
        if len(layout.children) > 1 and layout.children[len(layout.children) - 1].title != new:
            layout.children.remove(layout.children[len(layout.children) - 1])

        options = students if new == 'Students' else teachers
        dynamic_select = Select(title = '{}'.format(new), value = '', options = options)
        layout.children.append(dynamic_select)

select_data.on_change('value', update_layout)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. I added a couple of comments to that. Because in my real case I have a dataframe with multiple cases. I just wrote that example that was simple. I modified the question with a dataframe. I am wondering how can I do that in this case.

Comment: is it possible to do a similar menu without making widgets appearing and disappearing?

Comment: Do you mean to add permanently a new widget each time when you make a selection in the first one? Then just remove the line containing `layout.children.remove` and the proceeding `if` statement.

Comment: I would like to have a fixed widget that changes only the options.

Comment: Then you just assign a new list to the `options` property of a `Select `widget: `select.options = ['cats','dogs']`

Comment: I tried in my modified question but it does not work

Comment: I suggest posting a new question and providing a complete, runnable code including imports. Thanks

Comment: ok, I added a new one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56278118/python-how-to-make-multiple-selection-in-bokeh-with-a-fixed-widget